# How to conditionally filter results based on query parameter in Postgres

Tags: postgresql-9.2

Assuming I have a table say People and another table Address and have a requirement to fetch all people if no address location is given or only those residing in a location if address location is given, how can I write a query in Postgresql? If no input is present, results could be more and if it is present, I have to get a filtered result. Tried multiple variants of CASE WHEN, but did not help much. Any help/pointers will be of great value.

Thanks,
Paddy

Comment: Can you show your table schema & SQL ?

Comment: Sorry folks for jumping the gun early and posting the question, find out a query version using LEFT OUTER JOIN and CASE WHEN combo.